# Route [accounts.edit] not defined. (View: C:\Users\user pc\Desktop\app\resources\views\accounts\index.blade.php) on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i'm receiving this error when i update my user's accounts,
the index.blade file i use the button to update for different users

```
<tbody>
                        @foreach($users as $user)
                          <tr>
                            <td>{{ $user->accno }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $user->balance }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $user->amt }}</td>
                            <td><a href="{{ route('accounts.edit', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a></td>
                          </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
```

my route file where i include the route accounts.edit

```
Route::get('/accounts', 'AccountsController@index')->name('accounts.index');
Route::get('/accounts/{id}/edit', 'AccountsController@edit')->name('accounts.edit');
Route::get('/accounts/{id}', 'AccountsController@update')->name('accounts.update');
```

and this is my controller

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        return view('accounts.edit', compact('user'));
    }
```

Comment: 1. Type this command: `php artisan route:list` to see your route is defined 2. try clear your cache, some time laravel use cached route and your change has not been applied yet `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: What is result of command `php artisan route:list`?

Comment: ** |        | GET|HEAD | accounts               | accounts.index   | App\Http\Controllers\AccountsController@index                          | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | accounts/{id}          | accounts.update  | App\Http\Controllers\AccountsController@update                         | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD | accounts/{id}/edit     | accounts.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\AccountsController@edit**

Comment: i type the command php artisan route:list above, the accounts.edit is included in the route:list, but i`m still getting the error